# How to integrate Quickbooks Desktop with a custom web app?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to find a way to integrate Quickbooks Desktop with a custom web app. It doesn't seem that Intuit supports this using their IPP APIs.

Is there a way to integrate Quickbooks Desktop with a web app?

BTW, I did find Intuit's Web Connector, but it seems like that's not being developed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to integrate Quickbooks Desktop with a web app?

Yes, use the [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/us#QuickBooksDesktopSDK). More than likely, you'll want to use [the Web Connector](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview) (or, build your own replacement which acts on a similar concept).

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Quick follow up: looking at QBWC http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/ it doesn't really seem actively developed (for example, I couldn't find any link to it from main QB site or developer site). Do you know if QBWC is actively developed?

Comment: Pretty much the entire QuickBooks Windows SDK (the Web Connector included) is maintained... but doesn't really get any new amazing feature updates. It does work, and it does work reliably.

Comment: Also - there's links to it on this page: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QBD Connect](https://qbdconnect.com/) to integrate ALL apps with QuickBooks Desktop with ONE API.